# Removed From the lazy column list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Whenever I try to remove from the lazy column list I get `arrayIndexOutOfBoundException`
This is the array that

```
var productsList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Product>() }//I load products in this list
```

Whenever the user presses a certain button  I do the following

```
productsList.remove(item)
```

I get array `arrayIndexOutOfBoundException` this is how I loop as well

```
itemsIndexed(productsList) { index, item ->
```

Anyway to avoid that error

Whole code for those interested:

```
fun MyProducts(navController: NavController,myProductsViewModel: MyProductsViewModel= viewModel()) {
    var productsList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Product>() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    var currentImage = remember { mutableStateListOf<Int>() }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
       myProductsViewModel.getShop()
        productsList.addAll(myProductsViewModel.productsList)
        currentImage.addAll(List(productsList.size) {0})

    }
    var pickedImage: MutableState<String?> =remember { mutableStateOf("") }


    BackHandler() {
        navController.popBackStack()
    }
       LazyColumn(
           Modifier
               .fillMaxSize()
               .padding(start = 16.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ,state = listState
        ) {
           itemsIndexed(productsList) { index, item ->
                                   .clickable {when(icon){
                                       Icons.Default.Delete->{
                                           scope.launch {
                                               myProductsViewModel.removeProducts(item.product_id,item.shop_id,item)
                                            productsList.remove(item)
                                           }
                                       }
                                       Icons.Default.Edit->{

                                       }
```

I am accessing the same list in the rest of the code but I don't think it is relevant to the problem

Comment: At least tell exactly what line the exception arises.

Comment: Or the code block, if you're not sure of the exact line for some vague reason.

Comment: Share minimum reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The logcat doesn't show which line gives the exception most probably because I am using constraint layout. it's Just telling me that the arraysize=2 and index=2  so it is indexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a proper code example but it sounds like you are not updating the list and the lazy column properly so the item is removed from the list but the lazy column does not know about it.

Comment: How to let the lazy column know about it then?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you are generally having some bad practice in your code. For example:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
   myProductsViewModel.getShop()
    productsList.addAll(myProductsViewModel.productsList)
    currentImage.addAll(List(productsList.size) {0})
}
```

This all looks like stuff that should be done in the viewmodel. Generally a composable is supposed to convert state to UI, that means, it shouldnt contain any business logic. The code snipped I just showed looks like something that can be done in the viewmodel.

Having something like this

```
var productsList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Product>() }
```

and then adding the elements with a LaunchedEffect is not how composables are supposed to be used.

First your `myProductsViewModel.productsList` should be a LiveData object thats holding your product list. Then you are supposed to do the following:

```
val productList by myProductsViewModel.productsList.observeAsState(emptyList())
```

Then you show it in your composable. If you want to change the list content, you should call a method for that on the viewmodel, which then updates the livedata object of your list accordingly.

I you hope I explained in clearly enough. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: How to call the function that does the logic in the viewmodel?

Comment: You need to define a method: lets say `fun removeProduct(index: Int)` in your view model and then you call that method on an items click on the view model.

Comment: What about the function that loads all the existing products where to call it

Comment: Most probably in the init block of the view model

Comment: After removing element from the list the list doesn't get updated  and the compose function doesn't recompose although the array in the viewmodel is updated

Comment: You will also need to reassign the livedata.value so that the state changes and therefore a recomposition is triggered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237918/discussion-between-daniel-weidensdorfer-and-dark-night).